# Can I write Vimscript in my IdeaVim .ideavimrc file?

Tags: vim, webstorm, ideavim

I am experimenting with Vim mode in the various JetBrains editors, using their IdeaVim plugin.

I'm trying to port over some of the existing functionality from my native .vimrc file. However, I don't seem to be able to get even the simplest vimscript function to work in my `~/.ideavimrc` file.

After some searching I can't determine if this is something that IdeaVim even supports. Can I execute functions in the JetBrains editors with the IdeaVim plugin enabled?

Answer (score 4):

You can use only a very limited set of Vim commands like some "set" options, various "map" commands, etc. See the IdeaVim repository on GitHub for more info.

Comment: @bryankennedy No, you can use them only as top-level commands.